# How to sort a multi dimensional array in PHP alphabetically?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting

My API written in PHP (Codeigniter) outputs users based on a selected keyword how can I sort this array in alphabetical order before it outputs to JSON.

This is the output:

http://pastie.org/2402372

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Why not sorting it directly in your query at Model?

Comment: I cannot. The array is a combination of different queries.

Comment: I need to sort by first name.

Answer (score 2):

This one works. Tried, tested, and true:

```
function sort_by_lastname($a, $b) {
    $a = trim($a['user']['basic'][0]['lastname']);
    $b = trim($b['user']['basic'][0]['lastname']);
    return strcmp($a,$b);
}

uasort($array['contacts'],'sort_by_lastname');
```

Comment: You may use strcmp instead of two-times comparation

Comment: @RiaD thanks, forgot that it also returned 0 when equal. Code updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use usort for this:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Which enables you to sort using your own function.

Example:

```
$users = $your_array['contacts'];
// or $users = $your_array->contacts;

usort ($users, 'sort_by_lastname');

$your_array['contacts'] = $users;
// or $your_array->contacts = $users; if it's json instead of array

function sort_by_lastname($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['user']['basic']['lastname'], $b['user']['basic']['lastname']);
}
```

Comment: Sounds very interesting! I have looked a bit on it and I cannot construct a function that works with my array. Is it possible that you can show me how to use it?

Comment: Can I place the sort_by_lastname function in a helper and then use usort function in the controller? How can I use the code? I get error: Use of undefined constant sort_by_lastname - assumed 'sort_by_lastname'.

Comment: Still having problems I´m afraid.

Comment: @Jonathan Clark: perhaps it's best if we go to chat to see what the problem is

Comment: why not just `usort ($your_array['contacts'], 'sort_by_lastname');` ??

Comment: Removed my upvote as Matt is correct. If it gets fixed, I'll put it back.

Comment: @Matt: can you try? Seems it works as I assume.function sort_by_lastname($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['user']['basic']['lastname'], $b['user']['basic']['lastname']);
}
$x=array('c'=>
 array(
 array('user'=>
  array('basic'=>
   array('lastname'=>'y')
   )
  ),

array('user'=>
  array('basic'=>
   array('lastname'=>'x')
   )
  )



));

usort($x['c'],'sort_by_lastname');

var_dump($x);

Comment: It can't work. `$a['user']['basic']` is a JSON array. No associative keys. Look at @AlienWebguy's solution how he references the `['lastname']` index.